# Split a ReadableStream into lines

Tags: whatwg-streams-api

Say I have a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) object (from the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) web standard):

```js
let readableStream = (await fetch('http://example.com')).body;
```

I know I can read it chunk by chunk, where the chunk size usually depends on the network:

```js
for await (let chunk of readableStream) {
  let chunkString = new TextDecoder().decode(chunk);
  console.dir(chunkString);
}
```

But how do I read a ReadableStream line by line?

(Note that lines can span multiple chunks, so it's not enough to just split every chunk.)

Comment: In short: maintain a string buffer which is a concatenation of the strings from each chunk. They accumulate until you identify a newline sequence in an incoming chunk — at which point you use all of the text up until that newline sequence as your current value, and the remaining text after it starts the beginning of the new buffer.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315479/split-a-readablestream-into-lines#comment136056414_76315479) There's [a self-contained implementation in a TypeScript module in Deno's standard library](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/0.202.0/streams/text_line_stream.ts), and if you need a JS version, you can use the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1DVm) to transpile it.